# Empty space in table / Undefined control sequence in own command

Tags: tables, errors

I have written a macro that splits a number in its digits and writes them in a table and I have 2 questions about it. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor, etoolbox}
\newcommand*\mytablecontents{}
\newcommand*\numtostr[1]{
\renewcommand*\mytablecontents{}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\laenge}{ln(#1)/ln(10)+1}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\aziffer}{#1}
\foreach \i [remember=\aziffer as \aziffer] in {\laenge,...,1} {%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ziffer}{\aziffer/(10^(\i-1))}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\aziffer}{\aziffer-\ziffer*(10^(\i-1))}
    \xappto\mytablecontents{$\ziffer$}
    \if\i1
        \gappto\mytablecontents{\\}
    \else
        \gappto\mytablecontents{&}
    \fi
}%
\mytablecontents
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*{7}{|r}}
    \numtostr{6563}
    \numtostr{3475}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

1) When looking at the result one sees that the first column contains a lot of empty space. Why is that?

2) I have also tried to write a macro that uses as arguments two numbers and writes them in a table using the macro above:

```
\newcommand*{\test}[2]{%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\groesse}{ln(\i)/ln(10)+1}
\begin{tabular}{*{\groesse}{r}}
    \numtostr{#1}
    \numtostr{#2}
\end{tabular}
}%
```

Then `\test{123}{234}` gives the error "Undefined control sequence". Why does this happen?

Comment: Regarding the space in the first column: Take care of all the spaces that you introduce by your macro `\numtostr`. End all lines in the macro definition with a `%` sign, unless you know that it is not necessary.

Comment: Regarding the error: *Where* exactly did you use `\test{123}{234}`? Did you make sure that `\i` was defined in this place?

Comment: `\if\i1`  would be true if `\i` was `11` or `22` is that intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Make sure that you macro definition does not introduce unintended spaces.
- Define `\i` before using it when executing `\test`.
- As noted by David in the comments, the `\if` is buggy, as it yields true whenever `\i` expands to a number starting with two identical digits. Replace it e.g. by `\ifnum\i=1\relax`.

Here is your code with the corrections.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor, etoolbox}
\newcommand*\mytablecontents{}
\newcommand*\numtostr[1]{%
\renewcommand*\mytablecontents{}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\laenge}{ln(#1)/ln(10)+1}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\aziffer}{#1}%
\foreach \i [remember=\aziffer as \aziffer] in {\laenge,...,1} {%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ziffer}{\aziffer/(10^(\i-1))}%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\aziffer}{\aziffer-\ziffer*(10^(\i-1))}%
    \xappto\mytablecontents{$\ziffer$}%
    \ifnum\i=1\relax
        \gappto\mytablecontents{\\}%
    \else
        \gappto\mytablecontents{&}%
    \fi
}%
\mytablecontents
}%

\newcommand*{\test}[2]{%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\groesse}{ln(\i)/ln(10)+1}
\begin{tabular}{*{\groesse}{r}}
    \numtostr{#1}
    \numtostr{#2}
\end{tabular}
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*{7}{|r}}
    \numtostr{6563}
    \numtostr{3475}
\end{tabular}

\renewcommand\i{100}
\test{123}{234}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: as noted under the question, `\if` looks wrong....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the note. Initially I didn't check the logic of the program, as this wasn't asked for ...

Answer (score 3):

The excess spaces are due to unprotected end of lines.

Here's a different implementation that builds a table from

```
\digittable{<comma separated list of numbers>}
```

There is an optional argument to set the minimum number of shown digits (padded with blanks), see the example code. You can also input operation on integers, the macros will compute the result by themselves.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\digittable}{O{0}m}
 {
  \martin_digittable:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__martin_digittable_numbers_seq
\seq_new:N \l__martin_digittable_entry_seq
\int_new:N \l__martin_digittable_length_int
\tl_new:N \l__martin_digittable_body_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \martin_digittable:nn
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__martin_digittable_numbers_seq
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__martin_digittable_numbers_seq { \int_eval:n { ##1 } }
   }
  % compute the maximum length
  \int_zero:N \l__martin_digittable_length_int
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__martin_digittable_numbers_seq
   {
    \int_set:Nn \l__martin_digittable_length_int
     {
      \int_max:nn { \l__martin_digittable_length_int } { \tl_count:n { ##1 } }
     }
   }
  \int_set:Nn \l__martin_digittable_length_int
   {
    \int_max:nn { \l__martin_digittable_length_int } { #1 }
   }
  % build the table rows
  \tl_clear:N \l__martin_digittable_body_tl
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__martin_digittable_numbers_seq
   {% pad the current digit with \__martin_digittable_blank:
    % first split the current item at every token
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__martin_digittable_entry_seq { } { ##1 }
    % add to the left the needed amount of blanks
    \prg_replicate:nn { \l__martin_digittable_length_int - \tl_count:n { ##1 } }
     {
      \seq_put_left:Nn \l__martin_digittable_entry_seq { \__martin_digittable_blank: }
     }
    % form the next table row, by inserting & between items
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l__martin_digittable_body_tl
     {
      \seq_use:Nn \l__martin_digittable_entry_seq { & }
      \exp_not:N \\
     }
   }
  % produce the table
  \begin{tabular}{|*{\l__martin_digittable_length_int}{c|}}
  \hline
  \l__martin_digittable_body_tl
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__martin_digittable_blank:
 {
  \phantom{0}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\digittable{3329+3234,3475,212,1}

\bigskip

\digittable[6]{6563,3475,212,1}

\end{document}
```

[image]